# How can I make universal windows application responsive UI like News app

Tags: xaml, navigation, win-universal-app

I want to make a responsive UI design similar to one used in News and Mail app in Windows 10. It's hard to explain lets look at screenshots.

[image]

In "Interests" page if I resize the window like in mobile, it shows only left part of the page.

[image]

After click "My Interest"

It shows the right part of the page.

[image]

And also If I want to go back it follows this route. But it is actually only one page with two different part.

I want to make similar to this approach. Is there a template for that or can I make that easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer Bart has given is correct in that sense the techniques are needed to achieve this.
But there is a template / example available, called Master - Detail layout that will do what you need.

General use, show a list on the left side and details of selected item of the list on the right side if there is enough place. If screen is too small, show list on 1 page and detail of selected item on next page.

See code reference here: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlMasterDetail

And design reference here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn997765.aspx

Comment: For these particular screenshots you can use the master - detail template indeed.

Answer (score 1):

The term you're looking for is `Adaptive UI`. There's not really a template to do ALL the work for you (as in, you will still have to do the major layout work, otherwise all apps would look the same).

You'll use `VisualStateTriggers` and `RelativePanel` controls to layout your controls and change the layout based on certain cut-off points (320-548-1020 pixels width, or any number of your choice), like this partial sample from the lab linked below.

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup">
            <VisualState x:Name="VisualStateMin320">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="320"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="Metadata.(Grid.Column)" Value="0" />
                    <Setter Target="Metadata.(Grid.Row)" Value="1" />
                    <Setter Target="Metadata.(Grid.ColumnSpan)" Value="2" />
                    <Setter Target="Metadata.(Grid.RowSpan)" Value="1" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="VisualStateMin548">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="548"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="Metadata.(Grid.Column)" Value="0" />
                    <Setter Target="Metadata.(Grid.Row)" Value="1" />
                    <Setter Target="Metadata.(Grid.ColumnSpan)" Value="2" />
                    <Setter Target="Metadata.(Grid.RowSpan)" Value="1" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="VisualStateMin1024">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="1024"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="Metadata.(Grid.Column)" Value="1" />
                    <Setter Target="Metadata.(Grid.Row)" Value="0" />
                    <Setter Target="Metadata.(Grid.ColumnSpan)" Value="1" />
                    <Setter Target="Metadata.(Grid.RowSpan)" Value="2" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

    ....

</Grid>
```

A good point to get started is watch following [Channel 9 video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Windows/Developers-Guide-to-Windows-10-RTM/Adaptive-UI).

There's also a great hands-on lab (lab 2) available from the presenter on [GitHub](https://github.com/Windows-Readiness/WinDevHOLs).